# How to personalize a journey based on salesforce data?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a journey that gets injected whenever a contact gets added to the relevant campaign in SF.
In the journey email, AMPScript lookup is needed to look for a value in a DE with 2 PKs.

As far as I know, since it's SF data, I can only access _subscriberkey, then lookup the relevant data.

But since it's a DE with 2 PKs, that won't work.
And I need to access the other key which is linked in the attribute group: [journey](https://prnt.sc/xyu76n)

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

look into the "Salesforce Data" Entry Event, subtype "Salesforce Data".

Select campaignMember as object, then choose Contact ID to inject.
Now follow the wizard to screen 4 "Entry Data".

Here you can add additional data from the source object (campaign member) and directly related objects (campaign, contact) to be injected alongside the subscriberkey / contact ID as "journey data". This will make those fields immutable data throughout the journey, available splits as well as for personalization using their placeholders. You can find the placeholders written on Screen "5 Summary" of the wizard, e.g. "CampaignMember:Campaign:Id"

```
%%CampaignMember:Campaign:Id%%
```

is the according placeholder format to display the campaignID that relates to the campaignmember you injected. You can of course use those also for lookups.

Comment: thanks! will give it a try